# How to select child tag from JSON file using scala

Tags: scala

Good Day!!

I am writing a Scala code to select the multiple child tag from json file however I am not getting exact solution. The code looks like below,

**Code:**

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:/temp").getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").json("C:/Users/Desktop/data.json").select("type", "city", "id","name")

println(df.show())
```

**Data.json**

```
{"claims":[
      { "type":"Part B",
        "city":"Chennai",
            "subscriber":[
                { "id":11 },
                { "name":"Harvey" }
             ] },
      { "type":"Part D",
        "city":"Bangalore",
            "subscriber":[
                { "id":12 },
                { "name":"andrew" }
        ] } ]}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
type    city         subscriber/0/id      subscriber/1/name
Part B  Chennai         11                  Harvey
Part D  Bangalore       12                  Andrew
```

Please help me with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken Apache Spark expects each line to be a separate JSON object, so it will fail if you’ll try to load a pretty formatted JSON file.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets
http://jsonlines.org/examples/